# Javascript function(to sum elemnts of array) dossn't work

Tags: javascript

I make a function(in javascript) to sum the elements of an array and return the result ...
but there is a problem and the output of this function is "NaN"
but when i checked the type of variable , that was "number" :|
please please help me to solve this ...

```js
function arrSum(a) {
   var val = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
      val += a[i];
   }
      return val;
}
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var pass = arrSum(testArr);
document.write(pass);

// SHOW "NaN"
```

```
function arrSum(a) {
   var val = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
      val += a[i];
   }
      return val;
}
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var pass = arrSum(testArr);
document.write(typeof pass);

// SHOW "number"
```

i am sorry about my english. i am not good at it :)
and thank you for your helps ...

Comment: Where is `result` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to write **arrSum** function in one line with no loops using using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (ES5):

```js
function arrSum(arr) {
 return arr.reduce((sum, x) => sum + x);
}

var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var pass = arrSum(testArr);
document.write(pass);
```

Answer (score 3):

Very much simple syntax(for array sum).

```js
var test = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
sum = eval( test.join("+") );  //join will return string which is '1+2+3+4' and eval will evaluate it and give result which is sum of numbers.
console.log(sum);
```

You are `returning result` but your sum is in `val`.

And also for loop condition is `incorrect`.

The reason you are getting `NaN` because at last iteration you are doing `number`+`undefined` which will result in `NaN` and type of `NaN` is number.

Hope it's clear your doubt why you are getting `NaN` and `number`.

Below is demo of correct code.

```js
function arrSum(a) {
   var val = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      val += a[i];
   }
      return val;
}
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var pass = arrSum(testArr);
document.write(pass);
```

**For additional info**

Conversion rules

```
operand + operand = result
```

1. If at least one operand is an object, it is converted to a primitive value (string, number or boolean);
2. After conversion, if at least one operand is string type, the second operand is converted to string and the concatenation is executed;
3. In other case both operands are converted to numbers and arithmetic addition is executed.

If both operands are primitive types, then operator checks if at least one is string and executes the concatenation. In other case it just transforms everything to numbers and sum.

Example:-

```
var result = 12 + undefined; // NaN
```

Explanation:

1. `12 + undefined` (Because none of the operands is string, convert the undefined to a number NaN based on rule 3)
2. `12 + NaN` (Numbers addition)
3. `NaN`

Comment: It would be helpful to explain them why they're getting `NaN` and why their typeof prints `number`

Comment: but your explain was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

*For-loop*'s ending condition is incorrect, array's index is *0-based*

Make it

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
```

Also `return` val instead of `result`.

**Demo**

```js
function arrSum(a) {
   var val = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      val += a[i];
   }
      return val; //observe this line
}
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var pass = arrSum(testArr);
console.log(pass);
```

Comment: Also, the function returns an undefined variable.

Comment: @Amy yeah and that as well. Was just about to submit my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

The problems are `return result` and `for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++)`. You must use respectively `return val` and `for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)`.